# Error while linking an app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, error-handling

getting this error while linking an app, some one an idea?

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBCustomLoginDialog1 in ....
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

As i know i linking a file twice... budet how to fix it?

Comment: Did you `#include` the file rather than `#import` it?

Comment: Did you import a `.m` file by accident?

Comment: @titaniumdecoy what do you mean?

Comment: i have found the problem, I have 2 files for this class with same content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same .m file is likely included in your project twice. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337692/duplicate-symbol-objc-metaclass-classname) for suggestions on how this could have happened.