# llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with xcode error in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This may be a simple problem.

But im totally stuck with this error.

I integrated three 20 into my project.

I integrated the Sharekit also into the project and three20.

But whenever i compile the following error is showing.i can't figure this error.

Can anyone please help me this.Thanks in advace.

Error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SHKDelicious in /Users/icodingmacmini3/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Awesome-gqlhzchmnubhcbetpcfvbiccpdzu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a(SHKDelicious.o) and /Users/icodingmacmini3/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Awesome-gqlhzchmnubhcbetpcfvbiccpdzu/Build/Intermediates/Awesome.build/Debug-iphoneos/Awesome.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SHKDelicious.o for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linkage error. The meaning of this error is that , you have used the symbol SHKDelicious twice. Check the links below

[duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337692/duplicate-symbol-objc-metaclass-classname)

http://www.dizzey.com/development/ios/duplicate-symbols-when-linking-objectivec-static-libraries/

http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-development-darwin/171821-duplicate-symbol-_objc_metaclass_.html

Answer (score 2):

When ever you get a duplicate symbol check for imports. Some kind of cycle would have happened. Try importing in .m file rather than .h file it may solve the problem.

Also make sure you have not added the file twice.

Comment: is there a way to add sharekit in three20 and also in other view of same project